# Any way to use kqoauth for google-drive

Tags: qt, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I want to upload images to google-drive.I came across kqoauth which provides example for twitter.Can it be used for google drive and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

kQAuth implements OAuth 1.0, Google deprecated OAuth 1.0 and switched to OAuth 2.0. So, you can't use kQAuth to authorize and authenticate.